# Недоступность компонента wpf.

Tags: wpf, c#

Здравствуйте, я добавляю listbox на wpf форму. Вот замл:

```
<ListBox Height="311" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="503" />
```

Вот так обращаюсь:

```
listBox1.Item.Add("3333");
```

Когда пытаюсь обратиться к компоненту компилятор ругается:

```
The name 'listBox1' does not exist in the current context
```

Как это решить?
Листбокс находится в гриде.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А у вас в конструкторе формы вызывается метод `InitializeComponent()`?
В `xaml` файле у окна должно быть свойство `x:Class` указывающее на Ваш класс.
`ListBox1` будет доступно только из класса окна, возможно, вы объявляете `ListBox` в одном, а используете в другом.

Comment: Да дело было в этом, а как теперь вызывать один компонент из нескольких классов?

Comment: Использовать один элемент в разных классах не очень хорошо, но если нужно, тогда можно сделать public свойство которое будет возвращать этот элемент. Ну или просто передавать ссылку на ListBox в нужную функцию, что тоже не хорошо.